# Show that $ d(x, A) = 0 $ if, and only if, $ x \in \overline{A} $

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X $ be a metric space with distance $d$ and let $ A \subset X $ not empty.

**(a)** Show that $ d(x, A) = 0 $ if, and only if, $ x \in \overline{A} $

**(b)** Show that if $ A $ is compact, $ d (x, A) = d(x, a) $ for some $ a \in A $

**(c)** Define the $ \epsilon $ - neighborhood of $ A $ in $ X $ as the set $$U(A, \epsilon) = \{x : d(x, A) < \epsilon \}$$ Show that $ U (A, \epsilon) $ matches the union of the open balls $ B_{d}(a, \epsilon) $ for $ a \in A$.

**(d)** Suppose $ A $ is compact and let $ U $ be an open containing $ A $. Show that some $ \epsilon $ - neighborhood of $ A $ is contained in $ U $.

**(e)** Show that statement (d) is not true if we put $ A $ closed but not compact.

**Definition:** Let $ (X, d) $ be a metric space and $ A $ a non-empty subset of $ X $. For each $ x \in X $, we define the distance from $ x $ to $ A $ by the equation $$ d(x, A) = \inf \{d(x, a): a \in A \} $$

For part (a), if $ A $ has the property of the supreme, then I want to use the following inequality: $$ \rho(x, y) \leq d(x, y) \leq \sqrt{n} \rho(x, y) $$ where $ d $ is the euclidean distance and $ \rho $ is the distance of the supreme. However this seems to be a particular case of exercise. Is this reasoning correct? For the other paragraphs I have not concluded anything.

Comment: Arguing using definition of $d(x,A)$ should suffice.

Comment: I don't see what $\rho(x,y)$ means. Neither can I see that bringing such a quantity in is of any use.

Comment: The intuition is that if $d(x,A) = 0$ , then (by properties of infimum) for every $\epsilon$ for there is an $x_{\epsilon} \in A$ so that $d( x, x_{\epsilon} ) < \epsilon$. Turn this into a convergent sequence. This gives one direction, and the other is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491698/distx-a-0-if-and-only-if-x-in-overlinea-closure-of-a?rq=1)

(b) We first show that, for any non-empty set $E\subset X$, $f_E(x):=d(x,E)$ is continous. Given any $x,y,z\in X$, we have the inequality

$$d(y,z)\le d(x,y)+d(x,z)$$

Taking the inf over $z\in E$, we see that
$$
d(y,E)\le d(x,y)+d(x,E)
$$
Which implies

$$ d(y,E)-d(x,E)\le d(x,y)$$

By symmetry, we also have
$$ d(x,E)-d(y,E)\le d(x,y)$$
Therefore, 
$$|d(x,E)-d(y,E)|\le d(x,y)$$
The last inequality shows that $f_E$ is continuous (in fact Lipschitz).

In particular, given $x\in X$, $f_{\{x\}}$ is continuous, and so attains a minimum on the set $A$, say at $a\in A$. But then $d(x,a)=d(x,A)$.

(c) By definition of $d(x,A)$,

$$x\in U(A,\varepsilon)\iff d(x,A)<\varepsilon \iff \exists a\in A(d(x,a)<\varepsilon) \iff x\in \bigcup_{a\in A}B_\varepsilon (a)$$

(d) Since $U$ is open, $U^c$ is closed. By (a), $d(x,U^c)>0$ for every $x\in A$. Let $a\in A$ minimize the function $f_{U^c}$ on $A$. This is possible by compactness and continuity. Put $\varepsilon:=d(a,U^c)$. If $x\in A$ and $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$, then $y\not\in U^c$, i.e. $y\in U$. So, $B_\varepsilon (x)\subset U$. This holds for every $x\in A$, and so we are done by (c).

(e) Look at $A=\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ and $U=(0,\infty)$.